# Embarcadero Rad Studio Firemonkey Indy POP3 IPv6 socket error 11004

Tags: firemonkey, ipv6, indy, pop3

I have the following problem. I use Embarcadero Rad Studio 10.1 Berlin Firemonkey. I want to connect to a POP3 server within an IPv6 network where IPv4 is not enabled and I get the socket error # 11004 error. My code is:

```
int port = 110;
pop3->Host = ...
pop3->Username = ...
pop3->Password = ..
pop3->AuthType = patUserPass;
pop3->IOHandler = iOHandlerStack;
iOHandlerStack->IPVersion = TIdIPVersion::Id_IPv6;
pop3->UseTLS = utNoTLSSupport;
pop3->Port = port;
iOHandlerStack->Port = port;
try
{
    pop3->ConnectTimeout = 5000;
    pop3->Connect(); 
    int msgc = pop3->CheckMessages();
    pop3->Disconnect();
    ShowMessage("OK: " + IntToStr(msgc));
}
catch (Exception &exc)
{
    ShowMessage(exc.Message);
}
```

If I use the application within an IPv4 network then after connecting the IPVersion property is set to Id_IPv4 automatically and there is no problem.

Interesting thing is that the following code works within IPv6 network:

```
IdTCPClient->IPVersion = TIdIPVersion::Id_IPv6;
IdTCPClient->Host = ...
IdTCPClient->Port = 80;
IdTCPClient->Connect();
IdTCPClient->Disconnect();
ShowMessage("OK");
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `pop3->IPVersion` property (which is inherited from `TIdTCPClient`) instead of the `iOHandlerStack->IPVersion` property directly.

`Connect()` overrides the IOHandler's `IPVersion` property value with the higher layer `TIdTCPClient::IPVersion` property value.

So, if you are leaving `pop3->IPVersion` to its default value of `Id_IPv4`, that would explain why you can't connect using IPv6. And why your `TIdTCPClient` example works.

Also, you don't need to set the `iOHandlerStack->Port` property manually, `Connect()` handles that as well.

Comment: The problem is that IPVersion property of TIdPOP3 component is protected, this is why I used iohandler.

Comment: @Ferenc it shouldn't be protected in descendants. I'll fix that when I get a chance. In the meantime, you can use an access class to promote the property: `class TIdPOP3Access : public TIdPOP3 { public: __property IPVersion; }; ((TIdPOP3Access*)pop3)->IPVersion = Id_IPv6;`

Comment: @Ferenc I have opened a ticket in Indy's issue tracker for this: [Promote IPVersion property in TCP clients](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/184)